# Passing, Assigning and Displaying PHP variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to search through past questions, but I'm not sure how to phrase my question to get the answer I need.

I know basis HTML / CSS and I'm trying to learn PHP.

I have a WordPress membership site where I would like to pass a variable from one plugin and display it in another.

Take a look at https://ridesharedriversclub.com/generate-qr-code/

The QR Code form type defaults to "Business Card". I have been trying to make it to default to "URL".

I have also been trying to get the "referral URL" that displays above the form to display in the "URL" input field on the form where it currently shows "https://".

Here is the code that displays the URL above the form:

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'Your referral URL is: <strong>%s</strong>', 'affiliate-wp' ), esc_url( urldecode( affwp_get_affiliate_referral_url() ) ) ); ?></p>
```

Here is code for the form below the URL:

```
 <?php
 defined('SQR_PATH') or die();



/* Form for 'In Content' generator */
function getQRForm(){

 $fields = wpsqr_get_fields();
$f1 = $fields[0];
$f2 = $fields[1];
$display_dl = wpsqr_get_dl_bool();


$f = '
<div id="incontentqrgen">
<div id="wpqr_gen">

  <div class="wpsqr_field">'.$f1.'</div>

  <form name="qrin_form" id="qrin_form" method="post" action="">

    <input type="hidden" id="wpsqr_url" value="'.SQR_URL.'js/" />

    <div id="qrselect">
      Type:
      <select id="qrtype" name="qrtype">
      <option value="buscardqr">Business Card</option>
        <option value="urlqr">URL</option>
        <option value="messageqr">Message</option>
      </select>
    </div><div class="clear"></div>';


    if(wpsqr_color_choice()):
      $f .= '
      <div class="wpsqr_colorpicker">
        <p>Choose colors: 
          <input type="text" id="wpsqr_bg_color" name="wpsqr_bg_color" class="wpsqr_picker" value="'.wpsqr_get_bgcolor().'" />
          <input type="text" id="wpsqr_fg_color" name="wpsqr_fg_color" class="wpsqr_picker" value="'.wpsqr_get_fgcolor().'" />
        </p>
      </div>';
    endif;

    $f .='

    <div id="buscardqrid">
      <p>First Name:<br /><input type="text" name="first_name" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>
      <p>Last Name:<br /><input type="text" name="last_name" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>
      <p>Company Name:<br /><input type="text" name="company_name" class="in_box" value="" size="28"  /></p>
      <p>Title:<br /><input type="text" name="title" class="in_box" value="" size="28"  /></p>
      <p>Telephone:<br /><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>
      <p>Work Address:<br /><input type="text" name="work_address" id="addr" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>
      <p>City:<br /><input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="in_box" value="" size="28"  /></p>
      <p>State, ZIP Code:<br /><input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="in_box" value="" /></p>
      <p>Email Address<br /><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>
      <p>Website<br /><input type="text" name="website" class="in_box" value="https://" size="28" /></p>
      <p>Memo<br /><input type="text" name="notes" id="notes" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>
    </div>

    <div id="urlqrid">';

      if( wpsqr_require_name() ):
        $f .= '<p>Name:<br /><input type="text" name="first_name_url" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>';
      endif;

      $f .= '
      <p>URL<br /><input type="text" id="qrurl" name="qrurl" class="in_box" value="https://" size="28" /></p>
    </div>

    <div id="messageqrid">';

      if( wpsqr_require_name() ):
        $f .= '<p>Name:<br /><input type="text" name="first_name_message" class="in_box" value="" size="28" /></p>';
      endif;

      $f .= '

      <p>Message<br /><textarea id="qrmessage" name="qrmessage" class="in_box" value="" size="28" ></textarea></p>
    </div>
    <p style="text-align:right"><input type="submit" name="wrqrin_submit" id="wrqrin_submit" value="Generate" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="wpsqr_store" name="wpsqr_store" value="'.SQR_STORE.'" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ip_address" name="ip_address" value="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'" />
  </form>
  <img id="qrimagescr" src="" border="none" />';

  if($display_dl):
    $f .= '
    <div class="wpsqr_download">
      <div class="wpsqr_field">'.$f2.'</div>
      <div class="wpsqe_dl_img">
        Download: <a class="wpsqr_dl_jpg" href="">JPG</a> | <a class="wpsqr_dl_png" href="">PNG</a>
      </div>
    </div>';
  endif;  

  $f .='
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>';

 return $f;
 }

?>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Jack